# Javascript string to array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, arguments

I have a javascript array imported from a JSON file like: (Lets call it `jsonArray`)

```
"0": {
   "0":{
     Variables
   },
   "1":{
     Variables
   }
},
"1": {
   "0":{
     Variables
   },
   "1":{
     Variables
   },
   "2":{
     Variables
   },
   "3":{
     Variables
   }
}
```

In a function, I would like to be able to pass strings such as:

```
"1:2" or "1" or "0:0"
```

Which I can then split:

```
function myFunction(a) {
   var b = a.split(":");
   var c = ...
}
```

I would like to be able to access `jsonArray` using the values from that function's argument.
For example:

```
When I call myFunction("1:2"); this should happen: var c = jsonArray[1][2]

or myFunction("1"); -->  var c = jsonArray[1]
```

What can I do to make this happen? Or what would be a better way to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction(a) {
    var b = a.split(":");
    var c = myObject;
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        c = c[b[i]];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work (untested):

```
function myFunction (compositeKey){
    var keySplits = compositeKey.split(":");
    var scope = jsonArray;
    for (var n in keySplits){
        if (typeof scope[keySplits[n]] == "undefined"){ 
            return null; 
        }
        scope = scope[keySplits[n]];
    }
    return scope;
}

myFunction("1:2");
```

Comment: You are right, I am sorry - didn't checked the incoming answers while I was writing the code. I will be pay more attention to it next time.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started, although I simplified the JSON to be one level:

```
var data = [{'variable':'variable','variable':'variable'}];
var myFn = function(a, b){
  return a[b[0]][b[2]];
}
```

Test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/2bUgD/

Hopefully it provides a base for you to work with. You can, of course, very easily turn the function into a prototype function for a "class" or (ಠ_ಠ) for a built-in, and set it up to return values dynamically for different object depths, etc.